# Select siblings of blockcategories (Prestashop, Smarty)

Tags: smarty, prestashop

We have a blockcategories menu in Prestashop with about 400 categories total including all the subcategories, and this is creating too many links on each of our page, resulting in not-optimal onpage SEO.

I want to add rel="nofollow" and some Javascript to all links except the root and the selected category and it's children and siblings.

Example:
- Subcategory A (Root, dofollow)
- Subcategory A-1(Sibling of selected, dofollow)
- Subcategory A-2 (Selected, dofollow)
- Subcategory A-2-a (Child of selected, dofollow)
- Subcategory A-2-b (Child of selected, dofollow)
- Subcategory A-2-c (Child of selected, dofollow)
- Subcategory A-3 (Sibling of selected, dofollow)
- Subcategory B (Root, dofollow)
- Subcategory B-1 (Nofollow)
- Subcategory B-2 (Nofollow)
- Subcategory B-2-a (Nofollow)
- Subcategory B-2-b (Nofollow)
- Subcategory B-3 (Nofollow)
- Subcategory C (Root, dofollow)
- Subcategory D (Root, dofollow)

I have been successful with Selecting the Root, the Selected and the Children of the selected. However I've been unsuccessful with selecting the Siblings of the selected (That share the same Parent).

How do I Select the Siblings of the Selected Category within the Blockcategories .tpl files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by modifying blockcategories.php, blockcategories.tpl and category-tree-branch.tpl.

First in blockcategories.php I edited rows 148 and 246.

Row 148 is the getTree() where the module assign the return array called $node in the .tpl files. Here I add the following line to the array (I assign parent the id_parent value:

```
'parent' => $resultIds[$id_category]['id_parent']
```

At row 246 I add "currentCategoryParent" to the smarty->assign array.

```
$this->smarty->assign(array('currentCategory' => $category, 'currentCategoryId' => $category->id, 'currentCategoryParent' => $category->id_parent));
```

I can then access these variables from the .tpl files using $currentCategoryParent and $node.parent.

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop is using a nested set model to store its categories:

- http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2008/12/23/nested-set-in-mysql/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

This allows you to easily select a part of the tree (parents, children, siblings, etc.).

Each "Category" object has a **nleft** and **nright** member that will help you to perform these selections.

Another easier way is to use the **level_depth** member, all siblings will have an identical level_depth value.

You can modify the blockcategories.php file to add level_depth in the SELECT statement of hookLeftColumn(). Then in the category-tree-branch.tpl file, simple add a test:

```
{if $node.level_depth == ....}rel="nofollow"{/if}
```

Be careful, Google might not like the fact that one some pages a category is nofollow and dofollow on other pages.

Answer (score 0):

i've had very similar problem - i needed to change style of all siblings of the selected category so the solution is the same

you need to modify category-tree-branch.tpl

```
<li {if isset($last) && $last == 'true'}class="last"{/if}>
    {assign var="RET" value=""}
    {if $node.children|@count > 0}
        {foreach from=$node.children item=child name=categoryTreeBranch}
            {if $smarty.foreach.categoryTreeBranch.last}
                {include file="$branche_tpl_path" node=$child last='true' assign='childItems'}
            {else}
                {include file="$branche_tpl_path" node=$child last='false' assign='childItems'}
            {/if}
            {assign var="RET" value="{$RET}{$childItems}"}
        {/foreach}
    {/if}
    <a href="{$node.link|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}" {if $RET|strpos:'selected'} class="parentselect"{/if}{if isset($currentCategoryId) && $node.id == $currentCategoryId}class="selected"{/if}
        title="{$node.desc|strip_tags|trim|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}">{$node.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a>
    {if $RET}<ul>{$RET}</ul>{/if}
</li>
```

all you need is to put whatever you need between `{if $RET|strpos:'selected'}` and `{\if}` for active branch ...or change the condition for non-selected branch `{if $RET|strpos:'selected'==false}`